# Starting select after specific value

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

here is my problem. I'm trying to select a list of records after a specific one, so starting from this value I want to select the next one (and not the starting value).
My "filter" is a primary key, something like "NP-A6666".

Here is my code actually:

```
var listVU = _context.AVu
 .OrderByDescending(r => r.UpdateDate)
 .Select(x => new AVut
 {
     VuId = x.VuId
 })
 .Take(50)
 .AsNoTracking()
 .ToListAsync();

return await listVU;
```

I would do something like:

```
var listVU = _context.AVu
 .OrderByDescending(r => r.UpdateDate)
 ".StartingFromButExluding(p => p.VuId == "NP-A6666")"
 .Select(x => new AVut
 {
     VuId = x.VuId
 })
 .Take(50)
 .AsNoTracking()
 .ToListAsync();

return await listVU;
```

So I will get listVU as a list of 50 values right after NP-A6666 (from NP-A6667 to NP-A6717 ordered for UpdateDate).

Answer (score 2):

Use [SkipWhile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var listVU = _context.AVu
                 .OrderByDescending(r => r.UpdateDate)
                 .SkipWhile(p => !p.VuId.Equals("NP-A6666"))
                 .Select(x => new AVut
                 {
                     VuId = x.VuId
                 })
                 .Take(50)
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .ToListAsync();
```

Skipwhile runs sequentially through the enumerable, skipping elements where the predicate returns true - once the predicate returns false, in this case when the VuID = "NP-A6666", the remaining elements are returned as a new enumerable.

If you then want to get everything up to `VuID.Equals("NP-A6717")`, you can do the same thing with `TakeWhile` instead of `Take(50)`:

```
var listVU = _context.AVu
                 .OrderByDescending(r => r.UpdateDate)
                 .SkipWhile(p => !p.VuId.Equals("NP-A6666"))
                 .Select(x => new AVut
                 {
                     VuId = x.VuId
                 })
                 .TakeWhile(p => !p.Equals("NP-A6717"))
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .ToListAsync();
```

And If you're wanting to exclude the row that the SkipWhile is stopping on, just do `.Skip(1)` right after the `SkipWhile(p => !p.VuId.Equals("NP-A6666"))`

```
var listVU = _context.AVu
                 .OrderByDescending(r => r.UpdateDate)
                 .SkipWhile(p => !p.VuId.Equals("NP-A6666"))
                 .Skip(1)
                 .Select(x => new AVut
                 {
                     VuId = x.VuId
                 })
                 .Take(50)
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: .SkipWhile seems perfect for my scope, but I keep getting an error 500 internal server everytime I use it. Also if I use only .Skip(1) I get the same error.